# Comparing attribute values in XPath

Tags: xslt, xpath

I want to get the value of a specific node, specified by its `id` attribute. But the behaviour of my XSL parser, Saxon, is not how I expected it to work.

This is my XSL code:

```
<xsl:template match="synonyme">
    <xsl:element name="corr">
        <xsl:value-of select="@connecteur" />
        <xsl:value-of select="/liste/connecteur[@id=@connecteur]/forme[1]" />
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

I just matched a tag named `synonyme` which has a `connecteur` attribute. My code outputs the value of this attribute.

I also want to output the value of another node which has an `id` attribute matching the `connecteur` attribute of my currently matched `synonyme` tag. But no results are ever found for this query, the second `value-of` always has empty output.

If I write, e.g. `[@id='c160']`, where `c160` is the exact same thing that is output by the first `value-of`, it works! But not when comparing to the `@attribute` of my matched node. How can I fix this?

The XML is basically

```
<liste><connecteur id="c160"><forme>foo</forme></connecteur>
       <connecteur id="c161"><synonyme connecteur="c160" /></connecteur>
</liste>
```

and the expected output in place of the `synonyme` is `<corr>c160 foo</corr>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The predicate you use:

```
[@id=@connecteur]
```

is looking for an element with two attributes - `id` and `connecteur`- with equal values. To look for an element with an `id` attribute whose value matches the value of the current element's `connecteur` value, you need to use:

```
[@id=current()/@connecteur]
```

See: https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#function-current

---

A better solution would be to define  a **key** as:

```
<xsl:key name="ref" match="connecteur" use="@id" />
```

then use:

```
<xsl:value-of select="key('ref', @connecteur)/forme" />
```

to resolve the cross-reference.

See: https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#key