# how to select node with xpath where two attributes equal?

Tags: php, xpath, simplexml

This is a detailing of [my question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57299757/php-extract-multiple-data-from-html-table).
I have the following nodes which I want to select with xpath:

```
<tr>
    <td class="name" title="43PUS6551" datalabel="43PUS6551">
```

How should the xpath query be formulated to find all `//tr/td` nodes where the value of attribute `title` **is equal** to the value of attribute `datalabel`?

Surely totally easy - but I just can not get there and find nothing suitable here or anywhere else on the net.

Comment: PD https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14248063/xpath-to-select-element-by-attribute-value

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/40701099/2943403

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to use this XPath, with the `@` to indicate the attributes...

```
//tr/td[@title=@datalabel]
```